# How to remove Duplicate Values from a list in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a collection of ID list to be saved into the database

```
if(!session.ids)
session.ids = []

session.ids.add(params.id)
```

and I found out that list has duplicates, like

```
[1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 5]
```

Then I wanted to remove all duplicates by applying something like :

```
session.ids.removeAll{ //some clousure case }
```

I found only this:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I am not a Groovy person , but I believe you can do something like this :

```
[1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 5].unique { a, b -> a <=> b }
```

Have you tried [session.ids.unique()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique()) ?

Comment: it say null  session.ids is null when i use it like session.ids = session.ids.unique() and then i put it as session.ids?.unique() and at the end of the day session.ids was null.first case.

Comment: that clouser staff could have add more meaning to my further list operations thankyou.

Comment: Maybe just use a Set instead of List

Comment: This perfect when comparing a list of objects and looking for duplicates by looking at the members within the objects in that list.

Answer (score 61):

How about:

```
session.ids = session.ids.unique( false )
```

**Update**
Differentiation between `unique()` and `unique(false)` : the second one does not modify the original list.

```
def originalList = [1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 5]

//Mutate the original list
def newUniqueList = originalList.unique()
assert newUniqueList == [1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 5]
assert originalList  == [1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 5]

//Add duplicate items to the original list again
originalList << 2 << 4 << 10

// We added 2 to originalList, and they are in newUniqueList too! This is because
// they are the SAME list (we mutated the originalList, and set newUniqueList to
// represent the same object.
assert originalList == newUniqueList

//Do not mutate the original list
def secondUniqueList = originalList.unique( false )
assert secondUniqueList == [1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 5]
assert originalList     == [1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 10, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4, 10]
```

Comment: @danielad FYI, If you do not want to mutate the original list and create a new list every time use `unique(false)`. The original list with duplicate items is preserved. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro Can't believe I forgot that....I even think that was one of my additions to the language ;-) lol

Comment: @dmahapatro nice point ,which means you could have a couple of lists if you like one wiht duplicat removed using .unique() and another with already duplicated list using unique(false) ? is that right?

Comment: @danielad Correct. Have a look a the update to Tim's answer, hopefully that would give a clear picture.

Comment: @tim_yates I am just a preacher of the creator. ;)

Comment: @dmahapatro added another bit showing that adding the duplicates back to `originalList` affects `newUniqueList` as well

Answer (score 20):

Use unique

```
def list = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
println list.unique()
```

This will print

```
[a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 13):

```
def unique = myList as Set
```

Converts `myList` to a `Set`. When you use complex (self-defined classes) make sure you have thought about implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is intended that session.ids contain unique ids, then you could do:

```
if(!session.ids)
  session.ids = [] as Set
```

Then when you do:

```
session.ids.add(params.id)
```

duplicates will not be added.

Also you can use this syntax:

```
session.ids << params.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge two arrays and make elements unique:

```
def arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
def arr2 = [1,2,5,6,7,8]
def arr3 = [1,5,6,8,9]
```

Let's look at mergings:

```
arr1.addAll(arr2, arr3) 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 5, 6, 8, 9]]
def combined = arr1.flatten() 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 5, 6, 8, 9]
def combined = arr1.flatten().unique()
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


def combined = (arr1 + arr2 + arr3).flatten().unique()

def combined = (arr1 << arr2 << arr3).flatten().unique()

def combined = arr1.plus(arr2).plus(arr3).flatten().unique()
```

Output will be:

```
println combined
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is small update , if someone wants to fetch unique elements from Nested ArrayList

list.unique{ a, b -> a[0] <=> b[0]}

Comment: Please consider editing your answer and providing links for supporting evidence or further reading.