# Find and modify duplicate entries in a collection

Tags: groovy

I need to find and modify duplicate entries in a collection.

I can do the following, which works, but takes a couple of steps.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the final output indicating all the entries that have duplicates?

```
void "test find and mark duplicate entries"() {
    given:
    def sports = ["baseball", "basketball", "football", "basketball", "basketball", "football", "soccer", "volleyball"]

    when:
    def duplicateEntries = sports.findAll { sports.count(it) > 1 }.unique()

    then:
    duplicateEntries == ["basketball", "football"]

    when:
    sports = sports.collect {
        if (duplicateEntries.contains(it)) {
            return it + "-dupe"
        } else {
            return it
        }
    }

    then:
    sports == ["baseball", "basketball-dupe", "football-dupe", "basketball-dupe", "basketball-dupe", "football-dupe", "soccer", "volleyball"]
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465787/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-list-in-groovy) or [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2011/09/groovy-goodness-sort-or-remove.html) if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same complexity as the others answers, just more memory efficient ;-)

```
def sports = ["baseball", "basketball", "football", "basketball", "basketball", "football", "soccer", "volleyball"]
sports.collect { sports.count(it) > 1  ? "$it-dupe" : it }
```

Comment: This is concise and straight forward(okay, straight forward after reading relevant docs ..) . Must the accepted answer.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks! I had to modify it slightly to make the test pass, since collect doesn't modify the original collection, but this is much more straightforward than what I had.
`sports = sports.collect { sports.count(it) > 1  ? "$it-dupe" : it }`

Answer (score 2):

The following piece of code may be just a bit shorter but I wouldn't expect *miracles* here ;)

```
def sports = ["baseball", "basketball", "football", "basketball", "basketball", "football", "soccer", "volleyball"]
def duplicates = sports.countBy { it }.findAll { it.value > 1 }.keySet()
sports.collect { it in duplicates ? "$it-dupe" : it }
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending answer from @Opal. This one uses groupBy..

```
def sports = ["baseball", "basketball", "football", "basketball", "basketball", "football", "soccer", "volleyball"]
def groupBy=sports.groupBy ().collect { it.value.size()>1  ? "$it.key-dupe" : "$it.key" }
println( groupBy)
```

Comment: doesn't work : the last assertion will fail. you loose the order and the final list didn't have the same size as the expected list