# Elasticsearch: storing tags without duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, duplicates, set

**I want to store tags in my documents in a way that I won't have duplicates.**

My documents have a `Tags` field defined as:

```
...
"Tags": { "type": "string" }
...
```

I add the tags to its `Tags` field from Python:

```
es.update(index=ES_INDEX, doc_type=ES_DOC_TYPE, id=user_id, body=doc)
```

My update document:

```
doc = {
  "script": {
    "lang": "groovy",
    "inline": "ctx._source.Tags.addAll(tags)",
    "params": {
      "tags": [
        "c#",
        "winforms",
        "type-conversion",
        "decimal",
        "opacity"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but the tags are potentially duplicated.

**I want to deduplicate the tags before storing them. I basically want the `Tags` field to act as a set.**

Here's what I tried (based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17465831/318557)

```
...
"inline": "ctx._source.Tags.addAll(tags); ctx._source.Tags.unique();",
...
```

But it has no effect.

Is there a Groovy solution to do that? Or maybe some support from Elasticsearch for storing sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was using `.addAll()` on initialized arrays. Using a REST client gave me this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[DevHunt][192.168.1.98:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to execute script",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "error evaluating ctx._source.Tags.addAll(tags);",
      "script_stack": [],
      "script": "",
      "lang": "groovy",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "null_pointer_exception",
        "reason": "Cannot invoke method addAll() on null object"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The solution was to use:

```
...
"inline": "if(ctx._source.Tags == null) {ctx._source.Tags = [];}; ctx._source.Tags.addAll(tags); ctx._source.Tags.unique();",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is a groovy problem. Are you checking correct objects?

I have a following document indexed:

```
{
    "_index": "script",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "AV2Jd1zXM1eNU8lqyoZS",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "Tags": [
            "tag1",
            "decimal"
        ]
    }
}
```

and call:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:9200/script/test/AV2Jd1zXM1eNU8lqyoZS/_update \
  -d '{
  "script": {
    "lang": "groovy",
    "inline": "ctx._source.Tags.addAll(tags); ctx._source.Tags.unique();",
    "params": {
      "tags": [
        "c#",
        "winforms",
        "type-conversion",
        "decimal",
        "opacity",
        "aaa",
        "aaa"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Result:

```
{
    "_index": "script",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "AV2Jd1zXM1eNU8lqyoZS",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "Tags": [
            "tag1",
            "decimal",
            "c#",
            "winforms",
            "type-conversion",
            "opacity",
            "aaa"
        ]
}
```

So groovy works fine here, check it yourself with some REST client. You can event try to reassign the collection:

```
"inline": "ctx._source.Tags = ctx._source.Tags.unique(); ctx._source.Tags += tags.unique();",
```

Maybe it is more a problem with Python code?